# How select date in calendar with Selenium?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, calendar

Here is the html for calendar. How to select date using css selector, xpath or something else.

- http://wklej.org/id/2772453/ - FIRST CLICK ON CALENDAR
- http://wklej.org/id/2772455/ - SECOND CLICK ON CALENDAR

`ClickElementById("ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderCenter_ContentPlaceHolderBody_ContentPlaceHolderBody_dfSalesAgrementData_imgSetDate");`
`ClickElementByCssSelector("td:contains('Dzisiaj')");`

This works. But if i try to click on calendar again and select date this does not work. Only first time date selection works. I cant change date.

I have this. But that works only once too.

`ClickElementById("ctl00_MainContentPlaceHolder_dFieldContractEndDate_imgSetDate");
ClickElementByXPath("html/body/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[4]");`

Comment: This work but dont look good and is very slow - ClickElementById("ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderCenter_ContentPlaceHolderBody_ContentPlaceHolderBody_dfSalesAgrementData_imgSetDate");
            int i = 0;
            while (!(IsElementDisplayedByXpath("html/body/div[" + i + "]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[5]")))
            {
                i++;
            }
            
            
            ClickElementByXPath("html/body/div[" + i + "]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[6]");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a bit hard to understand and based on my understanding, can you please try this?

```
ClickElementByCssSelector("td[class='day selected today']");
```

Comment: You are awesome. THIS WORK. Sorry for my hard english. Can you help me if i want to select another date (not present day)?

Comment: @crisx, please tell me which date you want to select and please accept my answer above if it has solved your first question? thanks

Comment: @crisx, without looking at the actual GUI, I think you need to click at least two elements in order to get the date you want. 25.07.2016. You need to click July and 25th, while the year is 2016 by default. You can click on July by using `ClickElementByXPath("div[@class='combo']>div[7]");` but there are multiple 26th in your HTML, I am not sure which one you are after, is it possible to show me the actual GUI?

Comment: http://iv.pl/images/03281913836133111121.png this is 19.07.2016 //ClickElementByXPath("//body/div/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[3]");

Comment: is it possible to send me the actual link? I need to inspect its elements.